# C# Safe Cracking minigame not working as expected

Tags: c#, string, for-loop, int

**Background:**

I'm trying to make a little mini game for a game in my class and I'm having trouble getting this to work 100%. What's wrong is if you pass 20 guesses it prints the `generateCombo();` message infinitely, also I cant get it to go to the second number.

Anything helps, I'm new to code, just started this year.

Thanks in advance!

```
class Safe
{
    public bool safeLocked { get; set; }
    public int guesses { get; set; }
    public int cn1 { get; set; }
    public int cn2 { get; set; }
    public int cn3 { get; set; } 
    public int cn4 { get; set; }
    public int num1 { get; set; }
    public int num2 { get; set; }
    public int num3 { get; set; }
    public int num4 { get; set; }

}

safe.guesses = 0;
        safe.safeLocked = true;
        safe.cn1 = 0;
        safe.cn2 = 0;
        safe.cn3 = 0;
        safe.cn4 = 0;

public static void generateCombo()
    {

        //First number
        Random n1 = new Random();
        safe.num1 = n1.Next(1, 10);

        //Second number
        Random n2 = new Random();
        safe.num2 = n2.Next(1, 10);

        //Third number
        Random n3 = new Random();
        safe.num3 = n3.Next(1, 10);

        //Fourth number
        Random n4 = new Random();
        safe.num4 = n4.Next(1, 10);

        Console.WriteLine ("A new combonation has been generated.");
        Console.ReadLine ();
        safeCracking ();

    }

public static void printScreen()
    {
        Console.Clear ();
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.Write("Guesses: ");
        Console.ResetColor();
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", safe.guesses);
        Console.WriteLine("");

        Console.WriteLine("     =================================    ");
        Console.WriteLine("     |       |       |       |       |    ");
        Console.WriteLine("     |       |       |       |       |    ");
        Console.WriteLine("     |   {0}   |   {1}   |   {2}   |   {3}   |    ", safe.cn1, safe.cn2, safe.cn3, safe.cn4);
        Console.WriteLine("     |       |       |       |       |    ");
        Console.WriteLine("     |       |       |       |       |    ");
        Console.WriteLine("     =================================    ");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Guess the numbers of the combination one by one.");
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }


    public static void safeCracking()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

            if (safe.guesses == 20) {
                generateCombo ();
            }

            printScreen ();

            string numg;
            int numberG;

            try{
                numg = Console.ReadLine();
                numberG = int.Parse(numg);
            }   catch {
                numg = "";
                numberG = 0;
            }
            numberOf.puzzleGuess = numg;

            //Check number 4
            if (safe.cn3 < 0 && (numg == safe.num4.ToString ())) {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Is Correct!", numberOf.puzzleGuess);
                Console.ResetColor();
                safe.cn4 = numberG;
                Console.ReadLine();
            } 

            //Check number 3
            else if (safe.cn2 < 0 && (numg == safe.num3.ToString ())) {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Is Correct!", numberOf.puzzleGuess);
                Console.ResetColor();
                safe.cn3 = numberG;
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            //Check number 2
            else if (safe.cn1 < 0 && (numg == safe.num2.ToString())) {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Is Correct!", numberOf.puzzleGuess);
                Console.ResetColor();
                safe.cn2 = numberG;
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            //Check number 1
            else if (safe.cn1 == 0 && (numg == safe.num1.ToString())) {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Is Correct!", numberOf.puzzleGuess);
                Console.ResetColor();
                safe.cn1 = numberG;
                Console.ReadLine();
            } 

            else {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Is Incorrect!", numberOf.puzzleGuess);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to continue...");
                Console.ResetColor();
                Console.ReadLine();
                safe.guesses++;
                safeCracking();
            }

        }

        if (safe.safeLocked == false) {
            //Continue game here
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you edit your response and add the code for the 'safe' object as well?

Comment: we need to see the generateCombo() method.

Comment: @StfBln Got you

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw Done

Comment: Wait, you're telling me that your code prints the generateCombo() message over and over again, without doing the stuff in printScreen() or allowing you to try and enter another number? That sounds like a bug in generateCombo().

As far as your other issue, have you tried debugging your program and seeing what the values are of all the different parameters when things go wrong and comparing the values there to the values you expect?

Heck, doing this would show you what's causing your generateCombo problem.

Comment: @iheanyin his issue is whenever he calls generateCombo() method the loop inside safeCracking() is being reset to 0 hence it prints more than once.

Comment: @Josh what do you mean by " I cant get it to go to the second number.?"

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw I got that to work dont worry it was just the greater than and less than signs where backwards, my bad

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw the loop cannot be reset to zero by any code in safeCracking() or by any code called by safeCracking. After a call to generateCombo, execution will return to the loop and continue with the next statement. Since the only continue statement is further down...

Comment: @iheanyi Whats wrong is when you go past 20 guesses it prints the Console.WriteLine(); in generateCombo(); infinitely.

Comment: @iheanyi so you're telling me whenever the safeCracking() method is called the loop is not reset? if your answer is yes then i am afraid you're incorrect.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw that is correct. Whenever safeCracking() is called, a new loop starts. The generateCombo issue is simple. GenerateCombo calls SafeCracking. He's created an infinite loop.

Comment: K guys i have to go home rn so ill be back later :P

Comment: @iheanyi which is the point i am getting at. both methods are invoking eachother. ;)

Comment: No offense but you should probably have paid more attention in class 0.0. you created an infinite loop.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw ok, but let's be clear, the loop doesn't "reset" to zero. It doesn't help Josh to learn the wrong reason for things not working.

Comment: @iheanyi alright we will conclude it there. All I was trying to say is generateCombo() calls safeCracking() and then safeCracking() invokes generateCombo() and carries on like that. You obviously didn't understand what I was referring to initially, but I think we agree on this fact I have stated above. To put it simply, it's as you've said "it's an infinite loop.

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet Is a online class... I learnt it online form microsoft virtual academy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to generate one combo and guess that 20 times as opposed to regenerating a combo each time someone guesses (would make more sense for a game IMO). If that's the case you should move `generateCombo()` out of the for loop

```
if (safe.guesses == 20) {
            generateCombo();
            safe.guesses = 0;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
...
```

Also, You don't need `safeCracking();` in `generateCombo()`, since it's causing an infinite number of calls. Something calls the `safeCracking()` method to start the game, which calls `generateCombo()`, which calls a NEW `safeCracking()` and on. All of your for loops never move past the first iteration.

Edit: You should probably also remove the `safeCracking()` recursive call in the else. That one gets called every time you have a wrong number it seems, and pretty much restarts the game every time you have a wrong answer.

If you want the game to loop every 20 guesses, why not just put a `safeCracking()` call instead after the for loop. Make sure to read line for an "exit" or some command that a user can input to close the game.

```
try{
text = Console.ReadLine();
if(text.ToLower() == "exit")
   return
numberG = int.Parse(text);
}   catch {
            numberG = 0;
        }
```

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure all your logic to check if the guess is correct uses numg instead of numberG which you want. (Including numberOf.puzzleGuess = numg; which I think is supposed to = i?). Not really pertinent to the problem your asking about though.

Comment: I tried taking the generateCombo() out of the for loop and that did not seem to work. Also I took safeCracking() out of the generateCombo() and it does not work because after I execute generateCombo() it ends. Also this is just a little game inside of my game, just a little puzzle.

Comment: Well safe.guesses isn't 20 when you initially start the minigame so the if should probably be `if(safe.guess % 20 == 0)`. Other than that, yeah, the main issue is those calls are circular. and the flow of your program simply gets caught in a loop. Your code only seems to generateCombo() when safe.guesses hits 20 anyway.

Comment: By deduction, the original loop must have been the safeCracking() call in the else. That would keep creating a new for loop every time the else came around.

Comment: Since you're new to programming (yay!) and online courses like that don't have a teacher to go to you for help or feedback as to what you're doing wrong with your code, I've attached my simple program I used to debug your code and play your mingame. You should be able to run and play the game with just that code; and it has comments on most of the lines I commented out with my name and why I did it. Hope you learn and don't get discouraged! https://gist.github.com/RMSD/fdba4cc689ec81592a709e718386518c